# Bash script that allows one word as user input

Tags: linux, bash

Made a script that the user gives a "parameter" and it prints out if it is a file, directory or non of them. This is it :

```
    #!/bin/bash
read parametros
for filename in *
do
 if [ -f "$parametros" ];
 then
  echo "$parametros is a file"
 elif [ -d "$parametros" ];
 then
  echo "$parametros is a directory"
 else
  echo " There is not such file or directory"
 fi
 exit
done
```

Altough i want the user to be allowed to give only one word as a parameter. How do i make this happen ? (For example if user press space after first word there would be an error message showing "wrong input")

Comment: Why are you looping but ignoring `filename`?   Doing the loop over the `*` glob but exiting on the first iteration is not useful.

Comment: How would the user input a name of a file which **does** contain spaces?

Comment: Why are you looping at all? You loop over all files in the working directory, but never actually use the variable `filename` in your code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
#!/bin/bash
read parametros
if [[ "$parametros" = *[[:space:]]* ]]
then
  echo "wrong input"
elif [[ -f "$parametros" ]]
then
  echo "$parametros is a file"
elif [[ -d "$parametros" ]]
then
  echo "$parametros is a directory"
else
  echo " There is not such file or directory"
fi
```

See http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/031 for the difference between `[...]` and `[[...]]`.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use the `$#`. It gives the number of the parameters.
The code will be something like:

```
if [ "$#" -ne 1 ]; then
    printf 'ERROR!\n'
    exit 1
fi
```

Comment: Note: this would work if changing the script to accept arguments - vs. dynamically reading input during script run ("read parametros")

Answer (score 0):

First, I'm curious why you want to restrict to one word - a file or directory could have spaces in it, but maybe you are preventing that somehow in your context.

Here are a few ways you could approach it:

1. Validate the input after they enter it - check if it has any spaces, eg: `if [[ "parametros" == *" " ]]; then...`
2. Get one character at a time in a while loop, eg with: `read -n1 char`

   - Show an error if it's a space
   - Break the loop if it's 'enter'
   - Build up the overall string from the entered characters

1 is obviously much simpler, but maybe 2 is worth the effort for the instant feedback that you are hoping for?

Comment: A filename can also contain a newline, so breaking the loop if the input byte is a newline is not necessarily appropriate.

Comment: Just to be clear, my previous comment is in no way intended to endorse the practice of using whitespace in filenames.  Every filesystem ought to be mounted with an option that prevents such odious behavior.  But if you are going to allow whitespace in filenames, you have to expect any whitespace.